# Display data only in certain path reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to display comments only in the page they are coming from. I store them in a file where I store the path as well. I am using Docusaurus as a SSG. I added `<CommentBox />` on all of my .md pages. `CommentBox` component is composed of a form and the comment list.

```
//CommentBox.js
import CommentsList from "./CommentList";
import CommentForm from "./CommentForm";
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CommentForm />
                <CommentsList />
            </div>
        );
    }
  };
  export default CommentBox;
```

Here is my code for CommentList, the one that I want to appear only in the right path:

```js
//CommentList.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import commentList from '../../../static/comments/approved-comments_submissions.json'

const formatDate = (dateString) => {
    const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" }
    return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)
  }

  
const displayNbComments = (nbComm) => {
    if ( nbComm <= 1){
        return(
        <h3>{nbComm} commentaire</h3>
        );
    }
    return (
        <h3>{nbComm} commentaires</h3>
    );
}

const Comments = commentList.map((item) => {
    const dateString = item.created_at;
    const location = useLocation();
    const path = location.pathname;
    const pathComment = item.data.urlpage
    const blabla = item.data.commentaire;

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState( path === pathComment ? true : false);

    return(
      <>
      {display && (
        <div className={styles.comments} >
            <div className={styles.author}>
                <img
                src={"https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=" + item.data.name + "&background=random"}
                style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50 / 2, float: 'inherit'}}
                alt='userIcon'
                />
                <div className={styles.metadata}>
                    <div className={styles.fullName}>{item.data.name}</div>
                    <date>{formatDate(dateString)}</date>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>{item.data.commentaire}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      </>
    );
} )

class CommentsList extends React.Component {
  render() {
      const nbComm = Comments.length
      return (
          <div>
              <p></p>
              {displayNbComments(nbComm)}
              {Comments}
          </div>
      );
  }
};
export default CommentsList;
```

I then have a `CommentForm` component which is the form where data comes from.

Then, I created a `CommentBox` component to gather both my form and my CommentList.

however is does not compile, and for each page I have this error

```
[ERROR] Docusaurus Node/SSR could not render static page with path /carnets/italie/2020/j1/ because of following error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'components_CommentBox' before initialization
    at Object.Z (main:21021:29)
    at MDXContent (main:15271:7114)
    at d (main:84851:498)
    at bb (main:84854:16)
    at a.b.render (main:84860:43)
    at a.b.read (main:84859:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (main:84870:138)
    at doRender (main:18221:356)
    at async serverEntry_render (main:18217:284)
```

Thanks

Comment: Which specific line of code is producing that exact error?

Comment: @David, I am not sure, here is the full error `[ERROR] Docusaurus Node/SSR could not render static page with path /carnets/japon/j9/ because of following error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CommentBox' before initialization
    at Object.Z (main:21021:29)
    at MDXContent (main:15960:22731)
    at d (main:84851:498)
    at bb (main:84854:16)
    at a.b.render (main:84860:43)
    at a.b.read (main:84859:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (main:84870:138)
    at doRender (main:18221:356)
    at async serverEntry_render (main:18217:284)`

Comment: It'll be important to find out, mostly because there is nothing called `CommentBox` in the code shown.  So it's not at all clear how the code shown can produce that error.

Comment: @David, I have edited my question, I hope it is better to understand now ;) I think the error is produced because of the `display` condition in `const Comments`

Comment: It's *probably* because the code still needs additional debugging info, because it still doesn't contain anything called `CommentBox` as mentioned in the error.  Just doing a Ctrl-F on this page and looking for "CommentBox" shows that it's only in a code comment, the error message, and in conversation between us.  But it's nowhere in the actual code.  You're going to need to find specifically where the error is happening, rather than make essentially random guesses like "I think the error is produced because of the `display` condition".

Comment: @David I have tried to be a little bit more specific, and indeed, there was a spelling mistake in `CommentBox`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to answer my own question.

You cannot use hooks (`useLocation`) inside class components, you can only use them in functions. This was the main error.

So basically I created a `CommentList` function regrouping both my `Comment` and `CommentList` component.

Then, instead of using a `&& condition`, I used a `filter` before the `map`.

Which gives us:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import commentList from '../../../static/comments/approved-comments_submissions.json'

const formatDate = (dateString) => {
    const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" }
    return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)
  }

  
const displayNbComments = (nbComm) => {
    if ( nbComm <= 1){
        return(
        <h3>{nbComm} commentaire</h3>
        );
    }
    return (
        <h3>{nbComm} commentaires</h3>
    );
}

function CommentList() {
    
    const location = useLocation();
    const path = location.pathname;
    const nbComm = commentList.filter(item => item.data.urlpage === path).length;
    return (
        <div>
            <p></p>
            {displayNbComments(nbComm)}
            {commentList.filter(item => item.data.urlpage === path).map((item) => {
              const dateString = item.created_at;
              return(
              <>
                  <div className={styles.comments} >
                      <div className={styles.author}>
                          <img
                          src={"https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=" + item.data.name + "&background=random"}
                          style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50 / 2, float: 'inherit'}}
                          alt='userIcon'
                          />
                          <div className={styles.metadata}>
                              <div className={styles.fullName}>{item.data.name}</div>
                              <date>{formatDate(dateString)}</date>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <p>{item.data.commentaire}</p>
                  </div>
              </>
              );
              } 
              )}
        </div>
    );
}; 
export default CommentList;
```